# Python Numpy stack 2d arrays in vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So, I would like to stack couple 2d arrays to vector so it would look like this:

```
[[[0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]]
```

I can make smth like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=int)
b = np.zeros((5, 5), dtype=int)
c = np.stack((a, b), 0)
print(c)
```

To get this:

```
[[[0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]]
```

But I cant figure out how to add third 2d array to such vector or how to create such vector of 2d arrays iteratively in a loop. Append, stack, concat just dont keep the needed shape

So, any suggestions?
Thank you!

**Conclusion:**
Thanks to Tom and Mozway we've got two answers

Tom's:

```
data_x_train = x_train[np.where((y_train==0) | (y_train==1))
```

Mozway's:

```
out = np.empty((0,5,5))

while condition:
    # get new array
    a = XXX
    out = np.r_[out, a[None]]
out
```

Comment: How do you get the first output from the two arrays?

Comment: I didn't. This vector of len 3 is desirable result that I can't get

Comment: But, what is the logic to get it from two 2-dimensional arrays?

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous due to the zero-only arrays, if you have n arrays of same shape and want to stack them, do it as a single pass: `np.stack((a1, a2, a3, ..., an), 0)`

Comment: I'm trying to get specific 28x28 matrices from fashin_mnist dataset of 60000 pictures. Dataset is in shape of (60000, 28, 28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following arrays:

```
a = np.ones((5, 5), dtype=int)
b = np.ones((5, 5), dtype=int)*2
c = np.ones((5, 5), dtype=int)*3
```

You can stack all at once using:

```
np.stack((a, b, c), 0)
```

If you really need to add the arrays iteratively, you can use `np.r_`:

```
out = a[None]

for i in (b,c):
    out = np.r_[out, i[None]]
```

output:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]])
```

##### edit: if you do not know the arrays in advance

```
out = np.empty((0,5,5))

while condition:
    # get new array
    a = XXX
    out = np.r_[out, a[None]]
out
```

Comment: What if I don't know my a, b, c's yet and I'm finding them in a loop by some condition. Like desire = np.array([]); for i in range(1000): if arr1[i] == 1: desire = np.append(arr2[i])

Comment: @GlebS I added an alternative

Comment: Collect the `a,b,c` iteratively in a list, and do one stack at the end.  This is more efficient, and easier to get right.

Comment: @hpaulj I fully agree (see my first option), this was however OP's request to to this iteratively (maybe they need the intermediate result)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```py
np.tile(a, (3, 1, 1))

array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Edit:
Do you mean something like:

```
test = np.tile(a, (3000, 1, 1))
filtered_subset = test[[1, 10, 100], :, :]

array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want to iterate through big set of (60000, 28, 28) shape and add specific (28, 28) shape matrixes to a new vector. So it would be like (12000, 28, 28)

Comment: You are going to have to provide a better example, i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I've added what you might mean?

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZoE1p5HBiLbo7bLDk1sqCNupfHiQ7n7o?usp=sharing

Comment: data_x_train = np.array([])
data_y_train = np.array([])
for i in range(len(y_train)):
  if y_train[i] == 0 or y_train[i] == 1:
    data_x_train = np.append(data_x_train, x_train[i])
    data_y_train = np.append(data_y_train, y_train[i])
data_x_train = np.delete(data_x_train, 0, 0)
data_y_train = np.delete(data_y_train, 0, 0)

Comment: Im trying to get 12000 specific 28x28 matrixes from 60000 dataset to another vector

Comment: `data_x_train = x_train[np.where(y_train==0 or y_train==1)`

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I need! But I'm getting The "truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" and can't get how to use .any

Comment: `data_x_train = x_train[np.where((y_train==0) | (y_train==1))` should fix that

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll put your and Mozway's answers to post!

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)